# How to use Googlemaps and apply a Dijkstra algorithm but I don't know how to assign the vertices?

Tags: c#, maps

I'm using Xamarin (C#) to create a food delivery app, and I finished the other modules but I'm not sure how to proceed with applying a shortest route algorithm.

Do I manually identify the markers and pre-set them in the app after downloading the json file?

I can use the services to get my location and the destination, so I know my starting and end points.

I'm basically trying to replicate google's own map routing but less efficiently. I also want to avoid going off road too.

I am at a loss on how to proceed. Can anyone please give me an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Google Route?  Do you want to try every road from start to end location.  Google uses history info from other request to find routes.  To assign vertices you first have to locate the road.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I don't know how to assign the vertices if it gets the routes. 

The other thing I was considering was pre-setting all the vertices, but that would make it a weird jumble and would mean thousands of manual entries? 

It confuses me a bit how to proceed... but it gives me an idea. I will try looking into it, thanks!

Comment: Oh! Kind of like: 

https://github.com/venkat-abhi/Graph-routing-using-dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-and-google-maps

This guy used a pre-made dataset, which contains his nodes. 

But, the place I want to cover is too big (a city), and I want to automate the setting of the nodes for the algorithm to use. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The google routing is using history info of other people.  So the vertices are based on the history.  You do not have any history so you do not know if vertices are local streets or major highways.  The API does give intersections for a lat/long.  So you could get the corners of the city lat/long and then find intersections.  Then enumerate through the corners at equal distance North/South : East/West.  Search on following for "intersection" :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Intersections would be useful! I'll try it....